# Trying to sort an ArrayList of Objects by last name, then by first name if last names are the same

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I created an `ArrayList` from an array.

```
ArrayList <Person> PersonArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(PersonArray));
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Trying something like:

I have created getters `getLastName()` and `getFirstName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be using `comparing` along with `thenComparing`.

```
personArrayList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName)
                               .thenComparing(Person::getFirstName));
```

Comment: What does’Person::getLastName’ mean?

Comment: @Skemelio it's a [**method reference**](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx) which is equivalent to the following [**lambda**](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) `(Person person) -> person.getLastName()`. Essentially, the Comparator `Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName)
                               .thenComparing(Person::getFirstName)` first extracts the persons' last names for comparison and if they're the same extracts the persons' first names and compares them.